# OpenCV Mat rotation gets wrong result

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to rotate an image by 90 degrees. My code is like following:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Mat img = imread("/Users/chuanliu/Desktop/src4/p00.JPG");

    resize(img, img, Size(1024, 683));
    imwrite("/Users/chuanliu/Desktop/resize.jpg", img);
    Mat dst;
    Mat rot_mat = getRotationMatrix2D(Point(img.cols / 2.0, img.rows / 2.0), 90, 1);
    warpAffine(img, dst, rot_mat, Size(img.rows, img.cols));

    imwrite("/Users/chuanliu/Desktop/roatation.jpg", dst);

    return 0;
}
```

But the result is like following:

Before rotation:
[image]

After rotation:
[image]

It seems that the center of rotation has sth wrong. But I don't think I set a wrong center. Is there anyone can tell me what is wrong?

Comment: your expected result is the original image rotated without the black borders and without cropped border on the right?

Comment: @Micka Yes. I expected it is just in the middle without the black area

Comment: the rotation center is right, but the rotation is a homography so you'll have to move the image after rotation to be placed at the right location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The centre is specified in terms of the source image's dimensions `Point(img.cols / 2.0, img.rows / 2.0)` but you are not only rotating the image but swapping the width and height in the output size when calling `warpAffine`:

```
Size(img.rows, img.cols)
```

so it looks like you might need to specify the centre in terms of the output image coordinates; eg. `Point(rows/2, cols/2)`.

**Update:**

Nope, that's not the solution. There is actually a very simple and efficient method for rotating an image by 90 degrees: using the `cv::transpose()` function:

```
int main()
{
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("5syfi.jpg");
    cv::Mat img_rotated;

    cv::transpose(img, img_rotated);  

    cv::imwrite("out.jpg", img_rotated);

    return 0;
}
```

Using a combination of `cv::transpose()` (to rotate) and `cv::flip()` (to mirror vertically and horizontally) you can very quickly perform rotations by 90, 180 and 270 degrees.

Using `warpAffine()` is much more flexible, but it is also much more expensive (ie. slower) to calculate.  So if you only need to rotate by a multiple of 90deg, use `cv::transpose`.  If you need to rotate by an arbitrary angle, use the `warpAffine/warpPerspective` functions. @Micka's answer gives a great example of how to do that.

Comment: yes, you're right. Now I know the problem, thank you.

Comment: did you try it? for me it crops the image is cropped left and leaves a black border on the right because after rotation, the top-left  corner of the resulting image has negative coordinates.

Comment: Please verify with the updated answer. @Micka was right, the centre of rotation wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 2):

adapting my answer from:

[OpenCV 2.4.3 - warpPerspective with reversed homography on a cropped image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587274/opencv-2-4-3-warpperspective-with-reversed-homography-on-a-cropped-image/24425764#24425764)

you can use this code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("../inputData/rotationInput.jpg");

cv::imshow("input", img);

cv::Mat dst;
cv::Mat rot_mat = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(cv::Point(img.cols / 2.0, img.rows / 2.0), 90, 1);
//cv::warpAffine(img, dst, rot_mat, cv::Size(img.rows, img.cols));

// since I didnt write the code for affine transformations yet, we have to embed the affine rotation matrix in a perspective transformation
cv::Mat perspRotation = cv::Mat::eye(3,3, CV_64FC1);
for(int j=0; j<rot_mat.rows; ++j)
    for(int i=0; i<rot_mat.cols; ++i)
    {
        perspRotation.at<double>(j,i) = rot_mat.at<double>(j,i);
    }

// image boundary corners:
std::vector<cv::Point> imageCorners;
imageCorners.push_back(cv::Point(0,0));
imageCorners.push_back(cv::Point(img.cols,0));
imageCorners.push_back(cv::Point(img.cols,img.rows));
imageCorners.push_back(cv::Point(0,img.rows));

// look at where the image will be placed after transformation:
cv::Rect warpedImageRegion = computeWarpedContourRegion(imageCorners, perspRotation);

// adjust the transformation so that the top-left corner of the transformed image will be placed at (0,0) coordinate
cv::Mat adjustedTransformation = adjustHomography(warpedImageRegion, perspRotation);

// finally warp the image
cv::warpPerspective(img, dst, adjustedTransformation, warpedImageRegion.size());



//mwrite("/Users/chuanliu/Desktop/roatation.jpg", dst);
cv::imwrite("../outputData/rotationOutput.png", dst);
cv::imshow("out", dst);
cv::waitKey(0);

return 0;
}
```

which uses these helper functions:

```
cv::Rect computeWarpedContourRegion(const std::vector<cv::Point> & points, const cv::Mat & homography)
{
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> transformed_points(points.size());

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<points.size(); ++i)
    {
        // warp the points
        transformed_points[i].x = points[i].x * homography.at<double>(0,0) + points[i].y * homography.at<double>(0,1) + homography.at<double>(0,2) ;
        transformed_points[i].y = points[i].x * homography.at<double>(1,0) + points[i].y * homography.at<double>(1,1) + homography.at<double>(1,2) ;
    }

    // dehomogenization necessary?
    if(homography.rows == 3)
    {
        float homog_comp;
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<transformed_points.size(); ++i)
        {
            homog_comp = points[i].x * homography.at<double>(2,0) + points[i].y * homography.at<double>(2,1) + homography.at<double>(2,2) ;
            transformed_points[i].x /= homog_comp;
            transformed_points[i].y /= homog_comp;
        }
    }

    // now find the bounding box for these points:
    cv::Rect boundingBox = cv::boundingRect(transformed_points);
    return boundingBox;
}


cv::Mat adjustHomography(const cv::Rect & transformedRegion, const cv::Mat & homography)
{
    if(homography.rows == 2) throw("homography adjustement for affine matrix not implemented yet");

    // unit matrix
    cv::Mat correctionHomography = cv::Mat::eye(3,3,CV_64F);
    // correction translation
    correctionHomography.at<double>(0,2) = -transformedRegion.x;
    correctionHomography.at<double>(1,2) = -transformedRegion.y;


    return correctionHomography * homography;
}
```

and produces this output for 90°:

[image]

and this output for 33°

[image]

btw, if you only want to rotate for 90°/180° there might be much more efficient and more accurate (concerning interpolation) methods than image warping!!