# Rotating a image regarding a rotated bounding box?

Tags: python, opencv, rotation

I have a rotated bounding box for a face and I like to rotate the image to to deskew the bounding box. Each bounding box is defined by 4 vertices in a python list like `[["x":12, "y":24] ... ]`. I found some [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37177811/crop-rectangle-returned-by-minarearect-opencv-python) describing such transformation but they all do this in C++ level opencv so I could not see what is going on between variables passing function to function.

I use opencv 2.4.12 on python but could not find a way to do so. Would you share some pointers to help me?

Comment: are those 4 vertices a perfect (rotated) rectangle? 4 vertices can form an arbitrary quad. If you have a cv::RotatedRect instead, you know the angle and center directly and don't need to use the 4-vertices which make it more complicated.

Comment: These are just random vertices forming a rotated rectangle but in a python list as defined

Comment: for your pointlist you can use `rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)             # rect = ((center_x,center_y),(width,height),angle)` so you 'll know the center and the angle to rotate. Then you can create a homography and use warpAffine to rotate accordingly.