# How to crop a square shape around OpenCV contours, not rectangle?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a set of skin lesion images, and I'm using OpenCV in python to detect the lesion and crop around it thus reducing the size (the images have a lot of skin area that can be cropped out).

However I can't figure out how to have the resulting cropped image in a square shape. Any help would be appreciated.

So far I have slightly edited the code from this question: [How to crop the biggest object in image with python opencv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49577973/how-to-crop-the-biggest-object-in-image-with-python-opencv)

Here's a sample image... I tried to get the most normal SFW lesion I could find, sorry if it grosses anybody out: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqt1g.jpg

And here's the code. I have been adding to x, y, w, h (ie. x+20 etc) to see if I can get it into a square shape but I don't think that's the way to do it.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread("ISIC_0024313.jpg")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # convert to grayscale
# threshold to get just the signature (INVERTED)
retval, thresh_gray = cv2.threshold(gray, thresh=160, maxval=255, \
                                   type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh_gray,cv2.RETR_LIST, \
                                   cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Find object with the biggest bounding box
mx = (0,0,0,0)      # biggest bounding box so far
mx_area = 0
for cont in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cont)
    x, y, w, h = x-40, y-40, w+80,h+80 # make the bounding box a bit bigger
    area = w*h
    if area > mx_area:
        mx = x,y,w,h
        mx_area = area
x,y,w,h = mx

# Output to files
roi=img[y:y+h,x:x+w]

cv2.imshow("im",roi)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imwrite("cropped.png", roi)
```

And here's the output. Close but not close enough: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLWN8.png

How exactly can I ensure that the resulting crop is square? While also giving enough breathing space to encompass the whole lesion.

Thanks

Comment: all answers must include some simple bounds checking. ie. will min-x/y or max-x/y go off the edge of the image.  my suggestion is to not do your padding(-40 etc) until you make it square, then if there is room, pad it out.  I would also start by centering by using half the difference of h/w so it's moreorless centered.  Also, if you're looking to create data for a classifier, you may wish to store the coords separately and NOT crop....this will allow some dynamic crops made by a generator.

Comment: @user1269942 waiting to pad until I make a square sounds like a good idea, just need to figure out how to make a square.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just check to see which is bigger between h and w and set both equal before you select the sub array?  Something like:

```
if h > w:
    w = h
else:
    h = w

# Then select the sub-array:
roi=img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
```

Comment: One liner: `roi = img[y: y + max(h, w), x: x + max(h, w)]`

Comment: it'll be finicky, but you need to check your bounds.

Comment: @user1269942 I think that would be the case for the current code too since the original code is adding a random 80 pixels to each dimension without checking the max.

Comment: agreed. I suggested that he add that extra padding at the end of the operation.  there's an opportunity for an elegant solution here...go for it!