# What is an efficient way to crop out a slanted box from image?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, data-science

Image:

[image]

I have coordinates for the bounding polygon (not an exact rectangle).
How can I rotate and extract the meter from image in an efficient way?

```
array([[337, 300],
       [574, 348],
       [567, 378],
       [329, 337]], dtype=int32)
```

I've been able to rotate the image by

```
(h, w) = im.shape[:2]
center = (w // 2, h // 2)
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0)
rotated = cv2.warpAffine(im, M, (w, h), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
```

but this changes the coordinates of box too.

Expected output :

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crop Rectangle returned by minAreaRect OpenCV \[Python\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37177811/crop-rectangle-returned-by-minarearect-opencv-python)

Comment: but the box is slanted @nathancy

Comment: Oh I see if its slanted, then there are two ways you can crop it. One is to use a mask and extract the ROI, the second is to use a perspective transform to obtain a birds eye view of the image. Here's a good [tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want a Perspective Transform with 4 points to go from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2

# Set width and height of output image
W, H = 600, 200

# Load input image
img = cv2.imread('speedo.png')

# Define points in input image: top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left
pts0 = np.float32([[337,300],[574,348],[567,378],[329,337]])

# Define corresponding points in output image
pts1 = np.float32([[0,0],[W,0],[W,H],[0,H]])

# Get perspective transform and apply it
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts0,pts1)
result = cv2.warpPerspective(img,M,(W,H))

# Save reult
cv2.imwrite('result.png', result)
```

---

You can do the same thing much more simply with **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows. In the Terminal, or Command Prompt, you just run:

```
magick speedo.png -distort perspective '337,300 0,0 574,348 200,0 567,378 200,100 329,337 0,100' -crop 200x100+0+0 result.png
```

**Keywords**: Python, command-line, shell, ImageMagick, OpenCV, distort, perspective, warp, affine, 4-point, 4-pt, transform, image, image processing.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and is surprisingly much easier and efficient than the rotate and crop techniques prevalent otherwise. Thanks man !

Comment: Also if the box is an exact rectangle can we get a simpler solution?

Comment: If the box is an exact rectangle, aligned vertically or horizontally with the picture edges, you can just take a Numpy slice of the image, e.g. `speedo = image[10:100,80:200]`

Comment: Its not aligned with edges but in a slanted position. I have the 4 points of the rectangle how can I map it to a straight rectangle like **pts1** you specified i.e. I need the subimage to be of same size as the bounding box rectangle (Not distorted as your output above).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. My output image would be exactly like your desired result in your question if the coordinates you gave were more accurate. If you want a different result, please update your question to show exactly what you want. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry I figured it out. Your answer was a great help, Thanks !